# Anything similar to dryscape or selenium for PHP? (headless browser)

Tags: php

my client want's to build a bot that will take links from RSS feed and post them via G+ on this URL `https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm?hl=en&url=http://google.com`. As you can see it is not a from, it's heavy based on JS and I did create 10 lines of code that does that in C# and Python but my client for some reason want it to be in PHP.

So what are my options? I'm not sure there are any things like dryscape or selenium for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Well, things like this are most commonly done with [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) in PHP.

Comment: cURL is not an option. As far as I know it cannot emulate button click and let javascript do it's thing.

Comment: You can if you use ajax. Create a php script, call it via ajax request, and post onto G+ via javascript.

Comment: Why would it have to emulate button click? You only have to emulate GET/POST request that happens when button is clicked, you don't have to emulate button click itself. Use Google Developer Tools or Firebug and see what requests are made when data is submitted to wall and attempt to emulate this with cURL.

Comment: It's very complicated in my case, I'm trying to post new link in G+ wall.